# Java or C++ for my particular agent-based model (ABM)?

Tags: java, c++

I unfortunately need to develop an agent-based model. My background is C++; I'm decent but not a professional programmer. My goal is to determine whether, my background aside for the moment, the following kind of algorithm would be faster or dramatically easier to write in C++ or Java.

1. My agents will be of class `Host`. Their private member variables include their infection and immune statuses (type `int`) with respect to different strains. (In C++, I might use an `unordered_map` or `vector` to hold this information, depending on the number of strains.) I plan to keep track of all hosts in a vector, `vector< Host *> hosts` .
2. The program will need to know at any time all the particular hosts infected with a particular strain or with immunity to a particular strain. For each strain, I could thus maintain two separate structures, e.g., `vector< Host *> immune`  and `vector< Host *> infectious`  (I might make each two-dimensional, indexed by strain and then host).
3. Hosts can die. It seems like this creates a mess in C++, in that I would have to find the right individual to kill in `host` and search through the other structures (`immune` and `infectious`) to find all pointers to this object. **I'm under the impression that Java will delete all these pointers implicitly if I delete the underlying object.** Is this true? Is there a dramatically better way to do this in C++ than what I have here?

Thanks in advance for any help.

---

I should add that if I use C++, I will use smart pointers. That said, I still don't see a slick way to delete all pointers to an object when the object needs to go. (When a host dies, I want to delete it from memory.)

I realize there's a lot to learn in Java. I'm hoping someone with more perspective on the differences between the languages, and who can understand what I need to do (above), can tell me if one language will obviously be more efficient than another.

Comment: You "unfortunately" need to develop an agent-based model? Wow, a little bit of un-ethusiasm goes a long way!

Comment: Fair point. ABMs are something of a dirty word in my field, so I'm used to apologizing for being involved with them... like, we couldn't find an analytically tractable alternative, so here's this big, barely debuggable thing with more assumptions than you can wrap your head around. But they can be done properly and they can yield exciting results, and I believe mine has!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm under the impression that Java will delete all these pointers implicitly if I delete the underlying object. Is this true?

Nope.  You actually have it backwards; if you delete all the pointers, Java will delete the underlying object.  So you'll still need to search through all three of your data structures (`hosts`, `immune`, and `infectious`) to kill that particular host.

However, this "search" will be fast and simple if you use the right data structures; a `HashSet` will do the job very nicely.

```
    private HashSet<Host> hosts;
    private HashSet<Host> immune;
    private HashSet<Host> infectious;

    public void killHost(Host deadManWalking) {
        hosts.remove(deadManWalking);
        immune.remove(deadManWalking);
        infectious.remove(deadManWalking);
    }
```

It's really that simple, and will take place in O(lg n) time.  (Though you will have to override the `equals` and `hashCode` methods in your implementation of `Host`; this is not technically challenging.)

My memories of C++ are too hazy for me to give any sort of authoritative comparison between the two languages; I did a ton of C++ work in college, haven't touched it since.  Will C++ code run faster?  Done right and assuming you don't have any memory leaks, I'd suspect it would, though Java's rep as a slow language is mostly a holdover from its youth; it's pretty decent these days.  Easier to write?  Well, give that you'd be learning the language, probably not.  But the learning curve from C++ to Java is pretty gentle, and I personally don't miss C++ at all.  Once you know the languages, Java is, in my opinion, vastly easier to work with.  YMMV, natch, but it may well be worth the effort for you.

Comment: Thanks to you and the other commenters for correcting my bad ideas about Java. I had also forgotten about the existence of hash sets (or multi-index containers in Boost). In your example in Java, there is still only one instance of each host in memory, right? I absolutely want to avoid copying instances of an object. What you wrote looks easy in Java, but I'm not sure how to use pointers as keys for hash sets in C++. I will look into it. Thanks again.

Comment: Yup.  The HashSets will be collections of pointers; if the same Host appears in multiple HashSets, then what you'll have are multiple pointers to the same object.  Glad I could help.  :-)

Comment: ... and since nobody mentioned this:  there's actually no such thing as an explicit destructor in Java.  Deleting all the pointers to an object is actually the ONLY way to delete the object.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer your all questions, but

> I'm under the impression that Java will delete all these pointers implicitly if I delete the underlying object.

In Java you don't delete an object; instead, it gets effectively deleted when the reference count to it goes to zero. However, you may want to utilize [weak references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference) here; this way the object disappears when the strong reference count goes to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your impression is basicly backwards: Java will assume an object (the host in this case) is dead when there's no longer any pointer to give access to that object. At that point it'll clean up the object (automatically).

At a guess, however, there's one collection that "owns" the hosts, and would be responsible for deleting a host when it dies. The other pointers to the host don't own it. If that's the case, then in C++ you'd normally handle this by having the "owning" collection contain a `shared_ptr` to the host, and the other collections contain `weak_ptr`s to the host. To use the object via a `weak_ptr`, you have to first convert that to a `shared_ptr` that you can dereference to get to the host itself. If, however, the object has been deleted, the attempt at converting the `weak_ptr` to a `shared_ptr` will fail, and you'll know the host is dead (and you can then delete your reference to it).